# How to forbid xserver automatic restart

Tags: xserver

Pressing the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> restart x server.
Using the shell, `sudo killall lightdm` kills the x server **but it's re-started**. How to fordib automatic restart?

Comment: Why are you killing lightdm in this way, rather than gracefully stopping the service or switching to a non-graphical target?

Comment: Becauseto  I couldn't find a working solution to stop the service or switch to a non-graphical target that works.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? does `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target` not work, and if not what happens?

Comment: After a nvidia driver update, nothing works anymore (= black screen) including ctrl-alt-F1-6 to go to a shell.

Comment: So I need a way to totally stop the x-server, and *maybe* a "simple" console will work (I just guess that if the x-server is not reachable, Linux goes into "pure" command line). FYI I still can type what I want (login + "sudo reboot" works), I just type 
as if i was blind, in one of those ctrl-alt-F1-6 shells.